# Clock Generation with PWM?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, clock

I'm designing a device with a central MCU/MPU and two external peripherals. The MCU has an internal clock frequency of 110 MHz. I'd like to use the MCU to generate separate clock outputs for each of the two peripherals, but the frequencies needed by the peripherals aren't even factors of the internal clock frequency of 110 MHz. One peripheral requires either a 26 MHz or 38.4 MHz clock, and the second requires a 42 MHz clock.

There are multiple timer modules within the MCU that are capable of pulse width modulation (PWM). From what I gather, PWM can be used to generate different waveforms from a clock signal. Is there a way to use PWM to generate a "custom" clock signal? For instance, to use an input frequency of 110 MHz to generate a square pulse with a frequency of 26 MHz?

Edit: Adding information about MCU

To give some additional information, I'm currently looking at the STM32L552ME microcontroller from ST. The microcontroller has 3 PLL's: two are linked only with SAI modules. The other PLL drives the system clock, peripherals, and timer modules. From that PLL, the timer can have a base frequency of 220 or 110 MHz.

The external modules I'm going to drive are an ADC (42 MHz) and a 5 GHz wireless communication module (26 or 38.4 MHz). From what I understand, the timing for these devices is critical. I was hoping that I'd be able to run the clock generation with the MCU to save PCB space.

Comment: depending on the timer hardware, you could probably get 110/4 = 27.5 . If the micro has some more nicer/more-complex timer hardware, you might be able to get ratios like 3/8 of main clock etc without using mcu cycles. For 26MHz you probably need an external clock generator chip such as from [SiLabs](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/Si5351.pdf).

Comment: There are clock synthesis chips that can generate various clocks (very flexibly) from a master clock by PLL multipication and division. I don't think you can do what you need with the ARM chip you have in mind. At lower frequencies it's not difficult to use capture-compare.

Comment: Using the micro's PLLs it's not too difficult to get one of those frequencies you want, but 2 of them is probably not possible.

Comment: What MCU do you have in mind? Some have peripherals with arbitrary clock dividers, a fractional PLL, and can set timer compare registers to arbitrary values, so many frequencies can be made.

Comment: I added some additional information about the MCU I'm looking at. It has 16-bit timer modules, but I'm not very clear on how timer modules work to generate a clock signal. From my understanding, I thought that any output frequency had to be an even factor/multiple of the base frequency, i.e. 55 MHz or 27.5 MHz